# Finite dimensional vector space given by polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $C[t]$ be the (infinite dimensional) vector space of complex polynomials, and let $0 ≠ g \in C[t]$ be any nonzero complex polynomial.

Consider the transformation $ p(f): C[t] \to C[t], f \to g f$.

Prove that $V = C[t]/im(p)$ is a finite dimensional vector space, and figure out the dimension of V.

I hope I recall this assignment correctly, as it was the last task on my exam yesterday and I couldn't quite complete it due to time constraints and due to it's difficulty. My guess was that the dimension of V might be: $dimV = deg(g)$, but I wasn't really sure about it and didn't know how to prove it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to write $deg(g)$, referring to the degree of the polynomial g.

Answer (score 1):

Let $q \in C[t]$. Because $C[t]$ is a euclidean ring, we can write $q = fg + r$ for some $f \in C[t]$ and $r \in C[t]$ such that $\mathrm{deg}(r) < \mathrm{deg}(g)$. Let $\pi$ be the canonical projection from $C[t]$ to $V$. Clearly, $\pi(fg) = 0$, so we have $$ \pi(q) = r $$ As $\pi(C[t]) = V$ it follows that every polynomial in $V$ has degree smaller or equal to $\mathrm{deg}(g) - 1$, So we know $\dim(V) \leq \deg(g)$. If $\deg(r) < \deg(g)$ we know that $\pi(r) = r$, so $\dim(V) \geq \deg(g)$. In conclusion we have

$$ \dim(V) = \deg(g) $$

Comment: @ Ben West of course, sorry for that